# Exception handling in the SharePoint Workflow 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, workflow2013

My workflow is quite long and have a lot of Stages. Stages include stuff like

1. Create new Tasks
2. Send email to a few people.
3. Update some fields in the list.

Most of the times while sending email, workflow stuck there. Then looking at the workflow status it shows the error-

> RequestorId: 2bd83918-60ae-ced2-0000-000000000000. Details: An
>   unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow
>   instance. Exception details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value
>   cannot be null. Parameter name: Input at
>   Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext
>   context) at
>   System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance
>   instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
>   at
>   System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor
>   executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

The workflow does not continue to run its execution which results in the renaming steps failed to do their job.

I am having this issue for a very long time now and it causes me problem.

Is there any way we can handle exceptions in the workflows? So that if a steps fails we can handle it properly?

Answer (score 0):

We do not have exact exception handling in workflow as we have in server side coding (try ... catch .... finally) but we can definitely check for empty values before executing any step. 
In workflow we can make use of :

`If Column:Title is not equal to variable:xyz 
then do the following`

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing. Still getting exception. I am sending email to user which is entered in a People Picker control in InfoPath. But if I look at the list in the dialog that  `Email this user` workflow command bring, I cannot see the name the person there. But User Profile Service shows his name. Do you think this could be the reason?

Comment: Is the people picker name being stored in list ?

Comment: It is not stored in any list. I'm just sending email to the value entered in the People Picker control